# Voting app in android how to store radio button response and calculate vote.

Tags: android

I am developing a voting app in Android . am new in android and don't  understand how to store my radio button response on per click . 
if i have 10 voter in one polling station then 
my `count=10` 
if i have 2 party's

party 1

party2

on each time when voter click on radio button then how to calculate and collect the response from the both radio button and how to show the result who is won
election .

any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: post some code here about what you have done till now

Comment: you can save the in SharedPreferences or you can just make two variable for each party whenever user click on radio button just increase the count for that party

Comment: if (view.getId()==R.id.rdb_1)
        {
            if(rdb_1.isChecked())

            {

                Toast.makeText(this,"you vote for party1",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        }

        if (view.getId()==R.id.rdb_2)
        {
            if(rdb_2.isChecked())


            {
                Toast.makeText(this,"you vote for party2",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your given code in comment, Declare two global variables which stores count (say `party1` and `party2`) and initialise is to 0. Increase the count when `isChecked()` is `true` and reduce it when it is `false` according to party.

```
if (view.getId()==R.id.rdb_1) 
{ 
 if(rdb_1.isChecked()) {
 party1++;
 Toast.makeText(this,"you vote for party1",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
 }
 else party1--;
} 
if (view.getId()==R.id.rdb_2) 
{ 
 if(rdb_2.isChecked())  { 
     Toast.makeText(this,"you vote for party2",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
     party2++;
   } 
   else party2--;
} 
// store values of `party1` & `party2` in `SharedPreference`
```

Update `party1` and `party2` variable values in `SharedPreference` every time. And get values back from `SharedPreference` before checking your condition (`isChecked`)

Comment: Thank you for saving my day

Comment: U r welcome bro. You can up-vote my answer if it worked for u :)